# Issues about spring boot working with elasticsearch: NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: elasticsearch

I am totally new to elasticSearch and trying to develop some demo project with spring boot.
I can work well with elasticSearch via browsers using Kibana, however when I try to work with Spring Boot I always get the following error:

```
20180108 13:27:28.809 [elasticsearch[Ord][generic][T#2]] INFO o.e.c.transport - [Ord] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, disconnecting... 
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [][127.0.0.1:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] disconnected
```

The ElasticSearch instance runs on my local PC with just one single node, there is no clusters. In the elasticsearch.yml config file I set **cluster.name: test123** and 
**node.name: node-1**. And I didn't change anything else in this config file.I have only one ElasticSearch instance.

In the Application.properties of Spring boot project, the ElasticSearch related part is configured as the following:

`spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=test123
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=127.0.0.1:9300
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.*=
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true`

And the related dependencies in the build.gradle file is the as the following:

```
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:'+springBootVersion)
compile ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch')
```

The version of the Spring boot is '1.5.8.RELEASE'
And the elasticSearch I am using is 6.0.0

When I try to run the project I always get the error mentioned above.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE is not compatible with Elasticsearch 6.0.
The Spring Boot 1.5.x is compatible with Elasticsearch 2.4.x

You can check the incomplete table for the compatible version here: [Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch)

You can do either

- Using Spring Boot 1.5.x and Elasticsearch 2.4.x
- Using Spring Boot 2.0.0M7 and Elasticsearch 5.5
- Using Java Transport Client library for the latest Elasticsearch 6.x
- Using Java High REST Client

If you start from scratch, may be it is better to use Java High REST Client, since the transport client 
[will be deprecated in the future](http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, JSas, I am trying to change it to Spring Boot 2.0 M7 now. I will update my test result here later.